# Lexical analyzer output issue

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, lexical

This is my lexical analyzer code when I enter as an input the following :

```
/*This is an example */

program
        var a,b:integer;

begin

        a =2;

        b =a+5;

        write(a);

        if b==1 then write(a);

end
```

the output must be like this :

```
<res,program>
<res,var> <id,a>,<id,b>:<res,integer>;
<res,begin>
<id,a> <assign,=><num,2>;
<id,b> <assign,=><id,a><addop,+><num,5>;
<res,write>(<id,a>);
<res,if> <id,b><relop,==><num,1> <res,then> <res,write>(<id,a>);
<res,end>
```

but I my output is :

```
Lexical Error~/hedor1>exampler < input\ .txt 
<res,program><res,var><id,a>,<id,b>:<res,integer>;<res,begin><id,a><assign,=><num,2>;<id,b><assign,=><id,a><addop,+><num,5>;<res,write>(<id,a>);<res,if><id,b><relop,==><num,1><res,then><res,write>(<id,a>);<res,end>
```

I don't know why it just avoids the newline and doesnot print it to the output although I have defined that in my patterns section `\n                printf("\n");`
what is the problem?

Comment: Your Flex code has disappeared in your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your input do you have a single newline by itself. All you have are sequences of one or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs and newlines). Since you have a rule that matches that, Flex uses the longest match.

Flex generates a greedy parser, which tries to match as much of the input as possible. For example, if it sees the input **reality**, it doesn't stop after matching **real** and then go on and match **ity** as a separate token. Instead, it matches all of **reality**.

In the same way, in your input after the starting comment you have not one but *two* newlines (since there is an empty line there), and this will be matched by your **{whitespace}+** rule, instead of twice by the **\n** rule.

Comment: but in the input there is a newline in the end of the line! you don't have to write explicitly \n you should press "enter" key is not that right?!

Comment: There are several newlines in the input, but always in places where your **{whitespace}+** rule will match a longer sequence. I tried to clarify my answer a bit.